# How to "change password" is there is no password on WD passport

Tags: password-protection

I used WD passport ultra without a password. Now I want to put in a
password and can't. The only setting available is change password.

Comment: That's usually the right setting - you're changing the password from a null password to whatever it is that you want to use.

Comment: Yes, choose change password, and leave the old password field empty, type in a new password twice and press change.

Answer (score 1):

As with most services where you can choose it without a password, no password is considered a password too.

All you need to do is press the change password. It will ask you for your old password. Given that you did not set one, the old password field is left empty.

Fill in the rest as if you had a password set and change it that way.